# How do I do if statements in dictionaries to print a key and value if the value is bigger than one?

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
global_sulfur=0
global_charcoal=0
global_gun_powder=0
global_low_grade_fuel=0
global_metal_frags=0
global_stone=0
global_tech_trash=0
global_cloth=0
global_explosives=0
global_rope=0
global_small_stash=0
global_beancan_grenade=0
global_metal_pipe=0
global_spring=0
global_animal_fat=0

def calculate():
  list={"Sulfur" : global_sulfur ,"Charcoal" : global_charcoal ,"Gun Powder" : global_gun_powder ,"Low Grade Fuel" : global_low_grade_fuel , "Metal Frags" : global_metal_frags , "Stone" : global_stone , \
        "Tech Trash" : global_tech_trash ,"Cloth" : global_cloth ,"Explosives" : global_explosives ,"Rope" : global_rope ,"Small Stash" : global_small_stash ,"Beancan Grenades" : global_beancan_grenade ,"Metal Pipe" : global_metal_pipe \
        ,"Spring" : global_spring ,"Animal Fat" : global_animal_fat}
```

Theres 700+ more lines but i wanted to make this questions simple, just think of at least of the variables will have a value over one.

I've tried multiple ways and countless hours to try and find a way to make a function that will print both value and key if the value is over 1.

Comment: You shouldn't shadow `list`, especially not with something that *isn't actually a list*. Also you should read a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict.items` to loop over the key-value pairs.

```
data = { ... }

for k, v in data.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. If you dont mind can you explain 'k, v', i dont understand exactly how it works, besides from it makes two different variables, thank you

Comment: `k` and `v` are the names I gave to each key and value as the pairs are iterated through.